# Authlogic and password and password confirmation attributes - inaccessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, factory-bot

Im trying to test my successfully creates a new user after login (using authlogic). Ive added a couple of new fields to the user so just want to make sure that the user is saved properly.

The problem is despite creating a valid user factory, whenever i try to grab its attributes to post to the create method, password and password confirmation are being ommitted. I presuem this is a security method that authlogic performs in the background. This results in validations failing and the test failing.

Im wondering how do i get round this problem? I could just type the attributes out by hand but that doesnt seem very dry.

```
 context "on POST to :create" do
            context "on posting a valid user" do
                setup do
                    @user = Factory.build(:user)
                    post :create, :user => @user.attributes
                end
                should "be valid" do
                    assert @user.valid?
                end
                should_redirect_to("users sentences index page") { sentences_path() }
                should "add user to the db" do
                    assert User.find_by_username(@user.username)
                end
            end


##User factory
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.username {Factory.next(:username) }
  f.email { Factory.next(:email)}
  f.password_confirmation  "password"
  f.password "password"
  f.native_language {|nl| nl.association(:language)}
  f.second_language {|nl| nl.association(:language)}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely can't read the password and password_confirmation from the User object.  You will need to merge in the `:password` and `:password_confirmation` to the `@user.attributes` hash.  If you store that hash somewhere common with the rest of your factory definitions, it is not super dry, but it is better than hardcoding it into your test.

Comment: thanks for confirming that for me. ill just merge them with the attributes hash. thanks.