# Rails 3 and Factory Girl creating user only if attributes are passed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, authlogic, factory-bot

I'm using Rails 3 rc, Factory Girl, and Rspec, and Authlogic.
Is there any way or reason why this would happen:

When I create a user like this:

```
@user = Factory(:user)
```

I get an issue with password confirmation being "too short".

my factories.rb is

```
  Factory.define :user do |u| 
      u.username   "Test User"
      u.email      "TestUser@gmail.com"
      u.password   "aoeuaoeu"
      u.password_confirmation   "aoeuaoeu"
      #u.password_confirmation {|u| u.password}
  end
```

But when I create one as I pass in :password and :password_confirmation manually,
it works just fine.

```
@user = Factory(:user, :password => "aoeuaoeu", 
                       :password_confirmation => "aoeuaoeu")
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: You probably have an attr_protected call somewhere that's hiding the password_confirmation field.

Comment: It's not attr_protected - Factory Girl uses setters

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to the problem the person here had:

[Authlogic and password and password confirmation attributes - inaccessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612571/authlogic-and-password-and-password-confirmation-attributes-inaccessible)

The password and confirmation must be passed in the attributes hash like so:

```
before(:each) do  
    @attr = {  
    :name => "Example User",  
    :email => "user@example.com",  
    :password => "foobar",  
    :password_confirmation => "foobar"  
    }  
end
```

For more info see:

http://railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two#top